# Assign AWS public IP address to interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

An ec2 instance from a RHEL ami (i havent checked any other) only has the private address assigned to it.

i.e. `ip addr` yields:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:6d:c3:86:ce:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.39.16.198/20 brd 172.39.31.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::6d:c2ff:fe86:cee0/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

the public IP is working and the machine can be reached through it.
It can can access the internet via the VPC's gateway.

But how do I make sure the interface has the *public* IP, so outgoing packages actually contain the correct IP? This is necessary for ipsec to work properly.

Comment: As I said in my answer to the dupe question linked above, this is **not** a requirement for IPsec to work correctly. Is that question one you posted as well?

Comment: @EEAA , thanks, didn't find that question. Yes it's a dup. No it isnt mine.

Comment: OK, no problem. They were very similar questions, asked within days of each other, so I was suspicious. Well, the answer still stands. Having the public IP actually on your server interface is not a requirement for IPsec. And no, you cannot assign a public IP directly to an EC2 instance, VPC or otherwise.

Comment: yep, the other question contained the answer i was looking for. thanks! (should i mark Ricos answer as accepted? It _is_ correct)

Comment: Sure, mark it as accepted. This might eventually be closed as dupe, but that's fine. There's no harm in giving Rico the rep points he deserves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't explicitly assign public IPs to AWS instance at the OS level. Amazon has their datacenter behind a firewall(s) and the instances all have private IP addresses that are being NATed to a public IP.

So to the outside they look like a `public IP` but internally they have their `private IPs`.  If you are trying to get to your instance from the outside using the `public IP` should be enough to get to it as it maps directly to the `private IP` of your instance.

Now if you have an IPsec tunnel setup directly to your instance I believe the outgoing packets will have the `tunnel IP` address attached to your instance.

Comment: I believe you meant "can not" in your first sentence, correct?